$\lim_{ t \to 0} \int Q_{t} * f(x)e^{-2\pi i x \xi} \, dx = \int \lim_{ t \to 0 } Q_{t} * f(x)e^{-2 \pi ix \xi} \, dx $?
Let $Q_t(x)=\frac{1}{\pi} \frac{x}{t^{2}+x^{2}}$, assume $f \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$, my professor claimed that
$$
\lim_{ t \to 0} \int (Q_{t} * f)(x)e^{-2\pi i x \xi} \, dx  = \int \lim_{ t \to 0 } (Q_{t} * f)(x)e^{-2 \pi ix \xi} \, dx 
$$
I'm not sure why this hold $Q_{t}$ doesn't seem to be uniformly bounded by a $L^{1}$ function. $\frac{1}{x}$ is not in $L^{1}$ So I don't know how we can use DCT
This question from learning about Hilbert transform.

Just to be clear, ‘$*$’ is the convolution operator, right?

@Aruralreader Yeah

These are Fourier transforms, so use that the Fourier transform of a convolution is the product of the Fourier transforms in both sides of the equation.
